# Is there a better way to construct JSON syntax when using AWS SNS service?

Tags: ios, json, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS Simple Notification Service for sending push notifications between user devices. SNS uses JSON format to send remote-pushes as described here:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Swift/#push-notifications-and-track-user-actions

Currently whenever I want to create new remote push between devices, I would write something like this in Swift:

```
var dict = ["default": “default text", "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"sound\":\"\", \"content-available\":\"1\", \"priority\":\"5\"}, \”customparameter\":\”test\" }”]

let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: nil, error: nil)
request.message = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

//Publish to AWS-endpoint
...
```

This works but the part where I write the JSON is hard to read and prone to errors, is there more readable way to construct JSON for AWS-SNS service?

Comment: `dict` contans subdictionary. So you could create them, and then insert them into dict.

Comment: Are you trying to tell us that this API expects a JSON dictionary with one key/value pair where the value is a string containing text that could be parsed as JSON? Really?

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, really, but it's more reasonable and sensible than it appears.  The inner strings containing json objects are being passed through to downstream systems/subsystems.  This API is just the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the value if the APNS_SANDBOX key as a JSON string -  it would be better to also write this value as another dictionary, like

```
var dict = ["default": "default text",
            "APNS_SANDBOX": ["aps": ["sound": "", 
                                     "content-available": "1",
                                     "priority": "5"],            
                 "customparameter": "test"]
           ];
```

Comment: That's what any reasonable person would do. Note that this will _not_ generate the same JSON as the questioner's code. So either the API accepts data in rubbish format (when expecting a dictionary and it gets a string, it parses the string again), or one of these codes isn't going to work.

Comment: Your "APNS_SANDBOX" value is a dictionary (as any reasonable person would expect). The questioner's "APNS_SANDBOX" value is a string containing JSON that could be parsed to a dictionary.

Comment: You are right - the JSON string could of course be derived from a Dictionary again and then added to the final dictionary. Following the Amazon link, it seems that the amazon service just takes the string value of APNS_SANDBOX to create the necessary JSON for the iOS pushes ...

Comment: this did the trick for me, AWS-SNS documentation for iOS is terrible, I can't remember where I got the original example but it worked so I went with it until now.

Comment: oh, was a bit too eager. It worked partially, didn't give me error but when receiving same notification it defaults to the default message instead of actual content

Comment: See the comment from gnasher729 and my additional comment